# Bootstrap popover positioning

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

Is there a way to align bootstrap popover on "Right Bottom" of the clicked button instead of the "Right Middle"? It should be dynamic.

[image]

You can check the standard code here http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2915/

```
<a href="#" id="example" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Header" data-original-title="Text">pop</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @ColinCline thanks for comment, however which part is not clear? All I need is the advanced positioning of Bootstrap popover

Comment: I cant access to your link. That's why you have to add code in here to get more accurate answers (base on SO rules)

Comment: what position is right bottom, on the vertex? in the link, the image is clearly "Right" not "Right Bottom"

Comment: @ColinCline Thanks, edited the question

Comment: @Mindless So I need Make the alignment of the popup "Right Bottom" of the clicked button. See the edited image please.

Comment: @ColinCline btw your link is invalid

Comment: @FrontDev Check this out if this is what you looking for tell me to make it as an answer with explanation.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hprkw39w/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override bootstrap popover css to achieve what you want:

```
.popover {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.popover.right .arrow {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Check the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2916/

Comment: What about when content's height becomes to tall (look at the picture)? -1

Comment: I am only overriding the popover box. Not anything inside the box.

Comment: That was just an example. OP wanna achieve what is in picture. He wanted to popover always be in bottom not middle. In your example if you add some extra content to popover it will become middle eventually.

Comment: Yes, this is an example only, I am providing this as this will be the easiest solution, obviously margin should be changed accordingly.